# How to register client in local DNS

Tags: dns, hostname

I have a number of Ubuntu 14.04 clients, and Ubuntu 14.04 server running local DNS.  Currently the DHCP server is a router - going to change this.

How can I register the clients, either static or DHCP addressed, to the local DNS server?

I would like to reference the clients by their hostname.

I have this in my DNS conf files:

`/etc/bind/named.conf`:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

---

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "est1.lan" {

        type master;

        file "/etc/bind/for.est1.lan";

        allow-transfer { 192.168.51.251; };

        also-notify { 192.168.51.250; };

 };

zone "51.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {

        type master;

        file "/etc/bind/rev.est1.lan";

        allow-transfer { 192.168.51.251; };

        also-notify { 192.168.51.251; };

 };
```

---

`/etc/bind/rev.est1.lan`:

```
$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA     pri.est1.lan. root.est1.lan (

        2011071002  ;Serial

        3600        ;Refresh

        1800        ;Retry

        604800      ;Expire

        86400       ;Minimum TTL

)

@       IN  NS          pri.est1.lan.

@       IN  PTR         est1.lan.

pri     IN  A           192.168.51.250

250     IN  PTR         pri.est1.lan.
```

---

`/etc/bind/for.est1.lan`

```
$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA     pri.est1.lan. root.est1.lan (

        2011071002  ;Serial

        3600        ;Refresh

        1800        ;Retry

        604800      ;Expire

        86400       ;Minimum TTL

)

@       IN  NS          pri.est1.lan.

@       IN  PTR         est1.lan.

pri     IN  A           192.168.51.250

250     IN  PTR         pri.est1.lan.

prestonc@ChuckieEgg:/etc/bind$ cat for.est1.lan

$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA     pri.est1.lan. root.est1.lan (

        2011071001  ;Serial

        3600        ;Refresh

        1800        ;Retry

        604800      ;Expire

        86400       ;Minimum TTL

)

@       IN  NS          pri.est1.lan.

@       IN  A           192.168.51.250

pri     IN  A           192.168.51.250
```

---

IP address of this DNS server is 192.168.51.250
I have the forwarders set up OK.

---

On a client:

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp0s31f6

iface enp0s31f6 inet static

   host-name manic2

   address 192.168.51.50

   netmask 255.255.255.0

   network 192.168.51.0

   gateway 192.168.51.201

   dns-nameservers 192.168.51.250

   dns-search est1.lan

   dns-domain est1.lan
```

---

In a client using DHCP I have

```
send host-name = manic
```

in the `/etc/dchp/dhclient.conf` file.

What would I be missing?

Comment: Is everything after `prestonc@ChuckieEgg:/etc/bind$ cat for.est1.lan` under `/etc/bind/for.est1.lan` an older version of the file?

Comment: My typo!!  /etc/bind/for.est1.lan only has:
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     pri.est1.lan. root.est1.lan (
        2011071001  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          pri.est1.lan.
@       IN  A           192.168.51.250
pri     IN  A           192.168.51.250